# Limit the number of records affected by an Access query

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to retrive record with limit in MS-Access Database table?

I have to use update query; while using this I am getting a syntax error.

Example:

```
Update Report Set Status='Processing' where Status='No' LIMIT 10
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 5):

MS Access doesn't have a `LIMIT` field, but you can use this:

```
Update Report 
Set Status='Processing' 
where ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 ID 
    FROM Report WHERE Status='No' 
    ORDER BY ID
)
```

Just replace `ID` with your primary key, and this will update the top 10 records.

Now if you want to get something equivalent to `LIMIT(10,20)`, it gets a little more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [LittleBobbyTables' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11527052/6884) (which is correct), here's an example how to do `LIMIT(10,20)` in Access SQL:

[How to do MS Access database paging + search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914637/how-to-do-ms-access-database-paging-search/6916791#6916791)