# ORM and Microsoft Access options

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ms-access, orm, oledb

Our ASP.NET MVC site uses **SQL Server** and the **Awesome LLBLGen ORM tool** to write the **Entity Framework** for it. Perfect.

We just got a requirement that we need to allow the users to upload an **Access 2000** database with just dumb tables. Then update those tables and let the user download the Access file again. No flexibility :(

I am not allowed to alter the Access table to link it to SQL or add objects like procs.

Am I forced to use **System.Data.OleDb** and raw sql to modify the Access tables ( "Update table blah blah...")? We've been using ORMs for so long we don't know our options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What ORM can I use for Access 2007 - 2010? I'm after WPF binding to the tables etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138887/what-orm-can-i-use-for-access-2007-2010-im-after-wpf-binding-to-the-tables-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the Dapper project, open source, worked for our simple needs.

Comment: [Here is the Dapper GitHub project page](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).