# How to implement pagewise loading in MSAccess

Tags: sql, ms-access, pagination, qsqlquery

In my application that using MSAccess as DB, I need to implement pagewise loading with sql query.

I know how to load  first 10 records, thats by

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Product ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```

But how can I pick record that is from 10 to 20.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in Access SQL, but not as straightforward as in other database products.
*(for example MySQL, where it would be just `LIMIT 10,10`)*

Check out my answer here:
[How to do MS Access database paging + search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914637/how-to-do-ms-access-database-paging-search/6916791#6916791)

*(the code to build the SQL Statement is in C#, but of course you can do it in any other language as well. If you don't know C# and need help understanding my answer, just leave a comment here)*

Comment: I have created a query with yyour sample "select * from Product where dateAdded in (select top 10/*page size*/ sub.dateAdded"    from ( select top 3*10 tab.dateAdded from Product tab where catID = 100 order by tab.dateAdded ) sub order by sub.dateAdded desc ) order by dateAdded";
is this correct

Comment: This part looks strange: `top 10/*page size*/ ` Is "page size" a comment? If yes, remove it. Plus, you should calculate `PageNum * PageSize`, i.e. the finished SQL string should read `30`, not `3*10`.

Comment: ok, But I cant edit the comment of your answer so adding new comment 

"select * from Product where dateAdded in (select top 10 sub.dateAdded" from ( select top 30 tab.dateAdded from Product tab where catID = 100 order by tab.dateAdded ) sub order by sub.dateAdded desc ) order by dateAdded"

is this correct if 10 is page size and 3 is page number?

Comment: The quotes after `select top 10 sub.dateAdded" ` shouldn't be there. Apart from this, the query looks correct. Why don't you just run it and see if it works?

Comment: I'm an ios developer, in my webservice the querry is passing to server, then result dataset will get as a result