# Click a button in VB.NET form to display next set of rows from database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Is it possible in a VB.NET form to click a "Next" button to display the next set of data from an Access database?

My module is shown below.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\CITeval\system5\system5\evaluation.mdb;")
    Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public ds = New DataSet
    Public CurrentRow As Integer
End Module
```

What is the code for the form load? btnnext?

Comment: Hi, if you highlight code and click the `{}` button it will be marked up and will become readable.

Comment: Well do you have any method in your `Module1`? Show us what you've tried! :)

Comment: @john .. where would you show your rows ? .. textbox or what ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic question of server-side paging. At the very simplest add WHERE clause to your SELECT statement used in OleDbCommand. For example if your result has some kind of ID - increase parameter for WHERE statement with every btnNext click.

So for initial load it would be `WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 100`

For the first btnNext click it would be `WHERE ID BETWEEN 101 AND 200`

For the second btnNext click it would be `WHERE ID BETWEEN 201 AND 300`

etc.

Again this is a very basic approach (it could produce inconsistent results if your ID is not sequential) but that's the idea - to limit each consecutive result by some kind of condition.

Comment: give me your email i would like to chat with you sir

Comment: Sorry I don't tutor. You need to have a basic understanding of SQL and vb.net and there are plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: can you check my current system?? just try my update and next.,.,because it is the only not functional.,.please

Answer (score 0):

Yuriy Galanter already outlined the basic approach in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18563364/6884) (add a `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT` statement), but unfortunately it's not that easy to do in Access without advanced SQL knowledge.

Other database systems have a simple syntax for this, for example MySQL. The following query selects data from a table **in MySQL**, skips the first 30 rows and then selects the next 10:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 30, 10
```

**Unfortunately there's nothing like `LIMIT` in MS Access, but it's possible to create the same behaviour with some SQL subqueries.**

Check out the following link, where I answered a similar question:
[How to do MS Access database paging + search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914637/how-to-do-ms-access-database-paging-search/6916791#6916791)

Comment: Doesn't BETWEEN work in Access SQL? Although, I think the OP means 'next row' by 'set of data' rather than 'next n rows'

Comment: Yes, `BETWEEN` works. But I understand that the OP meant paging ("to display the next set of data"), and for paging, you can't use `BETWEEN` because you don't know the IDs of the next X rows in advance.

Comment: Yes, I must've been assuming an artificial key with no gaps - I'd just read Yuriy's answer below. But despite his use of 'set of data' I'm guessing the OP's trying to display a single row of data, with 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons.

Comment: Maybe - but that's still paging, just with a page size of one :-)

Comment: Well you got me there! :-) Anyway, if John Reguindin ever comes back he's got the choice of 'use a bindingsource with MoveNext/MovePrevious etc' from me for one-row-at-a-time and good coverage of paging from you and Yuriy.

Comment: I Share MY System is Teachers Evaluation

ihave a total of 20 questions .,.,but i will not load it all.,..,
i will have an initial load of 5 questions then if i click next button it will load 6-10 questions and so on.,.,I am asking about what is the code for the btn next!!!!!!!!!!could u printscreen codes >??????

BADLY Needed
TNX

Comment: The exact SQL query that you need is in the link at the bottom of my answer. You just need to write code to run the query and display the result in your form.

Comment: @ChristianSpecht tnx for help.,.Ill try it