# How to create SQL like "select * top n" on a Access DB

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select

I know how to set "top n", but if number of top depens on select result,
I don't know how to set number of top.

for example(This works well):

```
select top 50 * from tbl order by id
```

I want to set as follows

```
select top (select count(*) from tbl where id < 50) * from tbl order by id
```

but this SQL is invalid.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access 2010 Limit Query Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212290/access-2010-limit-query-results)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You'll have to create that SQL dynamically with VBA, and then assign it to a querydef.

Comment: @Andre is right. It can't be done dynamically in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understood that it was impossible.

Comment: Maybe this is over my head but I really can't see how returning the count of records where ID<50 to use as TOP N is different from `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID<50`.

Comment: I assume the example was (over-) simplified. @June7